# compatibility of ASP.net Pages with other OS es

Tags: asp.net

I was Planing to make my website and thought that either use ASP.net or Php as i have not used php but know c# so can do ASP.net.but problem that i came to mind as i make desktop apps are only for windows. what if i make a website in dot net (cross platform compatibility dose not hold for desktop apps) would users be able to open pages at their systems independent of os.

Comment: Independent of browser may be more important than independent of OS as some people may prefer Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari or Chrome as their preferred browser you do realize right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web pages are meant to be served accross multiple platforms, so you can use ANY server-side language you like because in the end, they all serve **HTML**.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net is a framework that produces HTML as an output, i.e. content generated in ASP.Net can be accessed by any platform that can display HTML. You could have problems with devices with no/limited javaScript support (old phones etc) but otherwise you're fine.